# Menu strip and adding menu items with events

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to add events to Clear and Exit.  Menu strip and items are present on form, not sure how to add an event for Clear and Exit.

```
MenuStrip thisMenuStrip = new MenuStrip();

ToolStripMenuItem thisFileItem = new ToolStripMenuItem("&File");
        thisFileItem.DropDownItems.Add("&Clear");
        thisFileItem.DropDownItems.Add("E&xit");
        thisMenuStrip.Items.Add(thisFileItem);
        this.Controls.Add(thisMenuStrip);
        thisMenuStrip.Name = "menuStrip";
        TabIndex = 0;

private void clearToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        DialogResult clearMessageBox = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to clear this form?",
            "Reset Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (clearMessageBox == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            thisMessageTextBox.Text = "";
            thisGenrePictureBox.Image = null;
        }
    }

 private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult exitMessageBox = MessageBox.Show("Do you really want to terminate this program?",
            "Exit Application", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

        if (exitMessageBox == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

If I need an event handler for Clear and Exit, would an object need to be created for each? e.g. ToolStripMenuItem clearToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem(); ... ToolStripMenuItem exitToolStripMenuItem = new ToolStripMenuItem();

I noticed a few examples like

```
private void clearToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
```

Does the above eliminate the need for a separate event handler like below.

```
thisClearFileItem.Click += new System.EventHandler(clearToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an overload of the [Add method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms160942(v=vs.110).aspx) that takes an EventHandler as a parameter

```
 thisFileItem.DropDownItems.Add("&Clear", null, clearToolStripMenuItem_Click);
 thisFileItem.DropDownItems.Add("E&xit", null,  exitToolStripMenuItem_Click);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input Steve, your solution worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the indexer of the `DropDownItems` property.

```
thisFileItem.DropDownItems.Add("&Clear");
thisFileItem.DropDownItems.Add("E&xit");

//Assuming 'clear' is the first item, its index would be 0
thisFileItem.DropDownItems[0].Click += clearToolStripMenuItem_Click;

//Assuming 'exit' is the second item, its index would be 1
thisFileItem.DropDownItems[1].Click += exitToolStripMenuItem_Click;
```

Comment: kbP, thank you to you as well, I tried your suggestion too and that worked fine. Have a good weekend to you both.

Comment: @Heavy - Thanks, you too!